# Apagar um registro da base de dados quando passar a data limite

Tags: mysql, sql

Como posso fazer para excluir automaticamente um registro da base de dados do MYSQL quando atingir uma data limite? lembrando estou usando um atributo data_termino do tipo Date

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE data_termino < '2017-09-21 00:00:00';
```

ou se for uma data superior use o > .. e por aí vai

Pode fazer algo mais automatizado por ex: (ultimos 6 meses)

```
delete from table where data_termino name < DATE_SUB(NOW() , INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
```

se quiser um intervalo use o **BETWEEN**

Comment: e como pegaria a data atual como se fosse do sistema, para comparar com a data-termino? Lembrando a exclusão tem que ser automática executada pelo SGBD sem interação do administrador

Comment: Data atual é o NOW()

Comment: então ficaria desta forma?
DELETE FROM table WHERE data_termino < DATE_SUB(NOW())

Comment: o que voce quer fazer? excluir todos os registros de agora pra trás?

Comment: se voce executar DELETE FROM table Where data_termino < NOW() 
Vai excluir tudo que está no momento exato do script pra trás.. ou seja vai limpar a tabela.

Comment: sim todos os registros que possuem data_termino menor que a data atual

Comment: é exatamente isso ai.. faça um teste antes com Select para ter certeza :) mas não tem erro. abraço.

Comment: Para ser de forma automática use o EVENT   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html